# I am trying to set the empty values in a csv file to zero in hive. But this code doesn't seem to work. What changes should I make?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hiveql, create-table, opencsv

### This is the input .csv file

"1","","Animation"

"2","Jumanji",""

"","Grumpier Old Men","Comedy"

### Hive Code

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies(movie_id int, movie_name string,genre string)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'

WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (

"separatorChar" = ",",

"quoteChar"     = "\"",

"serialization.null.format" = '0'

);

### Output

1               Animation

2       Jumanji

```
    Grumpier Old Men        Comedy
```

Answer (score 3):

Empty strings in csv are interpreted as empty strings, not NULLs. To represent NULL inside a delimited text file you should use "\N". Also Hive provides you a table property “serialization.null.format” which can be used to treat a character of your choice as null in Hive SQL. In your case it should be empty string "". To convert NULLs to zeroes use `NVL(col, 0)` or `COALESCE(col, 0)` function depending on your hive version (COALESCE should work for all).